# updating xamarin.forms and xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am developing in xamarin.forms for android and ios

I have upgrade to to latest xamarin.forms package 2.3.0.107 in the pcl and it works fine - no compilation errors.

when I try to upgrade the xamarin.android to the same version I get lots of packages error.

I have seen in some posts that there is not need to upgrade the xamarin.android because the xamarin.forms knows to take the latest / most suitable package of amarin.android. is it true ?

The default xamarin.android is from januray 2016 which is quite old...

Here are the list of errors I get...

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content directory.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content directory.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content directory.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist.    SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid            
Error       Reason: C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   SmartScout.Droid
```

Comment: I have current version of 2.0.0.6482 from november 2015

Comment: Have you tried deleting (back it up first to the desktop or something, just in case) your AppData\Local\Xamarin folder along with a clean/rebuild on your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try erase this file
C:\Users\asaf\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip
and build again

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you pretty explicitly what the error is:

> C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\android_m2repository_r10.zip is not a valid zip file How to fix it
>
> Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r10.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\content directory.